# Jestjs with Expo-cli. Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo

Jest doesn't seem to be able to use the component I imported.

This is commonly a problem with the way the exports/imports are set up, but my console logging shows that the component is being imported into the file, but not making it into the describe function (see inline comments below)

```
import ValidInput from '../components/ui/ValidInput';
console.log(typeof ValidInput) // 'function'

describe('ValidInput', () => {
    it('Renders succesfully', () => {
        console.log(typeof ValidInput) // 'undefined'
        const validInputInst = renderer.create(
            <View>
                <ValidInput 
                    inputType='email'
                    validationRules={{
                        isEmail: true,
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
        const ValidInput = validInputInst.root.findByType(ValidInput)
    })
})
```

The component:

```
export default class ValidInput extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }
...
```

Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Expected to be able to render the component

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the problem was in this line:

```
const ValidInput = validInputInst.root.findByType(ValidInput)
```

and another here:
`inputType='email'`

For some reason, while ValidInput is undefined in the scope of describe(), if you try to assign a variable called ValidInput (const ValidInput), after having imported something with the same name above, it will throw the Invariant Violation error as if you're trying to call something you HAVEN'T imported.